# Populate multiple placeholders in parent from child component in Angular4

Tags: angular

In my parent component I'm using a `<router-outlet>` which works fine to display the child html.

**How can I allow the child to specify other parts of the parent component as well?**

Here's what I've tried, but everything just gets rendered in the `router-outlet` placeholder.

Parent Component:

```
<header>
    ...
    <div #myheader></div>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Child Component:

```
<div #myheader> [Some HTML to be shown inside #myheader placeholder in parent] </div>
<div> [Rest of my html to be shown under router-outlet in parent</div>
```

The reason I need to do this is because the child component gets a lot of padding on either side, but the header runs full width, so it's not as simple as just specifying the child relative sub header in each child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building a service that has a property for your page header.

The ParentComponent can then access the service to bind to the property.

And each ChildComponent can set the property as it needs.

I have an example service here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

The code would look something like this:

**Service**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable() 
    export class HeaderService {
      headerText: string; 
    }
```

**Parent Component**

```
export class ParentComponent {

  get header():string { 
    return this.headerService.headerText; 
  } 

  constructor(public headerService: HeaderService) { } 
}
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<header>
    ...
    <div>{{ header }}</div>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child Component**

```
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(public headerService: HeaderService) { 
     this.headerService.headerText = ''; // <- Header text here
  } 
}
```

Comment: If I was passing html that contained things like check boxes, select list filters etc for manipulating data in the child component that would be an issue right? I probably should have been more clear that this dynamic html in the parent is really a toolbar that sites in the parent components html for the header navigation.